# Multiple column where_in clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, where-in

Below is codeigniter single column `where_in` clause `$this->db->where_in('x1',$val);`

how can I pass multiple column in CodeIgniter `where_in` clause like below MySQL query `select * from tab1 where (col1,col2) in ((1,2),(2,3))`
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your data array is like this(should be)

```
$val1 = array(1,2);
$val2 = array(2,3);
```

And query should be

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tab1');
$this->db->where_in('col1',$val1);
$this->db->or_where_in('col2',$val2);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```

---

Or else you can use

```
$this->db->query("select * from tab1 where (col1,col2) in ($val1,$val2)");
```

Comment: for example I updated only where col1 = 1 or 2 and col2 = 2 or 3 , but this updated also col1=1 and col2=3

Comment: change this and see `$this->db->or_where_in('col2',$val2);`

Comment: $data = array(
             approve' => 1
  );
             $this->db->where_in('third_id', $t_id);
             $this->db->where_in('_id', $s_id);
     $this->db->update(TAB, $data);

Comment: same thing happen for OR also

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

"$arr_1 = some_array;"

"$arr_2 = some array;"

If they are the same array just replace `$array_2` with `$arr_1`

```
$result = $this->db->select('*')->where_in('col1',$arr_1)->where_in('col2',$arr_2)->get('tab1')->result_array();
```

OR

```
$result = $this->db->select('*')->where_in('col1',$arr_1)->or_where_in('col2',$arr_2)->get('tab1')->result_array();
```